# Persistent storage API

Tags: javascript, storage

[This](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/06/persistent-storage) article gives this code snippet on how to create local storage which is persistent.

```
if (navigator.storage && navigator.storage.persist) 
  navigator.storage.persisted().then(persistent=>{
    if (persistent)
      console.log("Storage will not be cleared except by explicit user action");
    else
      console.log("Storage may be cleared by the UA under storage pressure.");
  });
```

But it doesn't explain much. For example  what is `navigator`?
Where can I find more details about this API?
Can I use it with indexedDB?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings can I access it from Service Worker? Where is API on how to actually store the data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.localStorage` which has no expiration date. Please refer to [wiki](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

**Setting Items**

```
localStorage.setItem("Name", "AurA");
```

**Getting Items**

```
localStorage.getItem(“Name”);
```

**Removing items**

```
localStorage.removeItem("Name");
```

In case this does not suffice as it has a small size limitation, better options are

1. WebSQL database
2. Indexed database
3. Filesystem api
4. Application Cache

The size limitation based on various browser version can be checked at https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/quota-research/

Comment: This doesn't suit me because it has limitations on size 5 MB, isn't it? That is why I am looking for persistent storage

Comment: @johna I have edited the answer to add storage options with bigger size

Comment: SQL is depreceted isn't it? application cache isn't recommended by MDN, check their page. IndexedDB has problem because browser can delete data if it reaches certain limits. Can you expand on Filesystem API?